# Problems rendering the Unicode replacement character

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to display the Unicode replacement character, but some combination of font and page encoding seems to be causing the character to show up invisibly in the browser. I can highlight the browser content and copy-paste it into a text editor and see the question-in-a-box glyph, so the character is there, but the browser displays no glyph.

I'm processing a text file with a `java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder` object (using the "REPLACE" option for `onUnmappable`), so it should process all inputs and if there are unmappable outputs I should see the replacement character (which is being left as the default).

I'm displaying this content in a jsp which is tagged as utf-8 like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
```

And also like this:

```
meta charset='utf-8'
```

(first element in the head)

Initially, my page has a `font-family` CSS setting of 'Courier New', but I've tried various fonts after looking at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font). Something is making the Unicode replacement glyph invisible in the rendered page.

Comment: well, it's definitely something I'm doing that's causing my problem, everything I can find relating to displaying those sorts of characters boil down to "make sure you're serving the page with UTF-8" as well as "serve the AJAX via UTF-8"... beyond that, font might be an issue, but it's most likely a charset mismatch somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to change the file format it self into UTF-8 from the editor .

Comment: changing the encoding of the origination file is not an option, my code is going to have to "any" input files, decode the data and ajax it onto the page.  The page is UTF-8, and the data is being served into the page after it loads via AJAX & JSON... I've tried specifying the CharacterEncoding on the ajax response as both UTF-8 and as the encoding I deduced from the origination file, no change.